# Removing a character from a Java string

Tags: java

I made a calculator in Java with a GUI and I can get it to give me proper results. I made the results look like this:

```
    JButton btn_Result = new JButton("=");
    btn_Result.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
            ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
            try {
                aResult = String.valueOf(engine.eval(textArea.getText()));
                textArea.setText(null);
                textArea.append(" = " + aResult);
            } catch (ScriptException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

So when I click another number, I want it to remove the = character so I can continue with another evaluation. What would be an efficient and quick way to achieve these results?

So after tinkering around a lot, I found the solution was very simple and I am very tired.

```
            if (bResult == null) {
                textArea.append(" / ");
            }
            else if (bResult.charAt(1) == '=') {
                textArea.setText(aResult + " / ");
            }
```

Thank you everyone who responded!

Answer (score 0):

Try something along the lines of:

```
String s = textArea.getText();
s = s.replace("=", "");
textArea.setText(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [String.subString](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int)) method as following.

```
String s = textArea.getText().subString(3); // Removing spaces as well
textArea.setText(s);
```

This method call will remove 3 characters from start of the `String`.